# What does each character of the `mode` mean when creating inodes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, file-permissions, mkdir

There's many guides out there on creating files/directories with Python that just say set `mode` to `0o777` or something, but what does each character actually mean?

For example, in the [official documentation for the `os` python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#mkdir-modebits):

> os.makedirs(name, mode=`0o777`, exist_ok=False)
>
> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
>
> The mode parameter is passed to mkdir() for creating the leaf directory; see the `mkdir() description` for how it is interpreted.

Which links to the `mkdir() description`, stating:

> os.mkdir(path, mode=0o777, *, dir_fd=None)¶
>
> ```
> Create a directory named path with numeric mode mode.
>
> If the directory already exists, FileExistsError is raised.
>
> On some systems, mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current umask value is first masked out. If bits other than the last 9 (i.e. the last 3 digits of the octal representation of the mode) are set, their meaning is platform-dependent. On some platforms, they are ignored and you should call chmod() explicitly to set them.
>
> This function can also support paths relative to directory descriptors.
>
> It is also possible to create temporary directories; see the tempfile module’s tempfile.mkdtemp() function.
>
> Raises an auditing event os.mkdir with arguments path, mode, dir_fd.
>
> New in version 3.3: The dir_fd argument.
>
> Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.
> ```

...but that still doesn't define what `0o777` means and what all the possible options are.

Where is it *actually* documented what all the possible options are for the mode values on all platforms and what they mean?

EDIT: At first I'd assumed that the first zero was the setuid bit (but with this strange "o" mashed between it and the rest of the permissions), but now I think that `0o` is just a prefix for the **octal** string that follows. But if that's the case, then is `0o0754` valid on all platforms? Where is this *actually* documented?

Comment: The docs for [mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) have a paragraph on this, which includes a link to the docs for [chmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chmod) where all the values are given. The [stat module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) provides further details on each value.